# Can lambda be used with off-policy Reinforcement Learning and experiential replay?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

DQN uses off-policy RL in order to learn an optimal policy from experiential data collected by following ANY policy e.g. observing an expert, previous non-optimal policies etc.

The experience is a collection of data of the form:

(s1, a1, r2, s2)

Here r2 is the actual reward received immediately after executing a1.

The experiences are used to set up supervised learning examples of the form:

Net INPUT: (s1,a1), Net TARGET:  r2 + gamma*argmax(a, Q(s2,a)))

Can r2 be computed by using lambda with eligibility traces ?  I am guessing it cannot, because that would make r2 dependent on the policy used to generate the experiences, which is not the policy being learnt.

Is lambda only applicable to on-policy RL ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that with *off-policy* reinforcement learning algorithms, eligibility traces should be applied taking into account some considerations. The reason is exactly what you have stated.

However, even it's less efficient than in *on-policy* methods, traces can be also useful in *off-policy* algos. In [Sutton & Barto's book (Chapter 7. Elegibility traces, Section 6)](http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node78.html) appears a great explanation for the case of Q-learning, which can be applied to other cases:

> Recall that Q-learning is an off-policy method, meaning that the
>   policy learned about need not be the same as the one used to select
>   actions. In particular, Q-learning learns about the greedy policy
>   while it typically follows a policy involving exploratory
>   actions--occasional selections of actions that are suboptimal
>   according to . Because of this, special care is required when
>   introducing eligibility traces.
>
> Suppose we are backing up the state-action pair at time . Suppose that
>   on the next two time steps the agent selects the greedy action, but on
>   the third, at time , the agent selects an exploratory, nongreedy
>   action. In learning about the value of the greedy policy at we can use
>   subsequent experience only as long as the greedy policy is being
>   followed. Thus, we can use the one-step and two-step returns, but not,
>   in this case, the three-step return. The -step returns for all no
>   longer have any necessary relationship to the greedy policy.